# Is there a way to adjust the text size (trying to change text from language to other inside exe PE file) using hex editors

Tags: windows, winapi, character-encoding, arm, disassembly

What I'm trying to do is to translate an application interface language from Korean to English

I've added a new section using CFF Explorer because the application doesn't have a size to extend the translated text

Then I used Ghidra to change the address for the text to the new address location

The problem I've faced is that the new text is cropped at specific character
eg.
The original text `USB를 읽고 있습니다.` and the new text `Reading The USB`
the problem is the new text appears like this `Reading The US` without the last character, and this problem appears in different places I've tried to change the text with the same approach, I know that this problem is related to the text size but I can't find where I can change the text size

here is a sample of code taken from IDA

```
.text:00049784 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00049784
.text:00049784
.text:00049784 sub_49784                               ; CODE XREF: sub_491B0+50↑p
.text:00049784                                         ; DATA XREF: .pdata:00616468↓o
.text:00049784
.text:00049784 var_3C          = -0x3C
.text:00049784 var_38          = -0x38
.text:00049784 var_34          = -0x34
.text:00049784 var_30          = -0x30
.text:00049784 var_2C          = -0x2C
.text:00049784 var_28          = -0x28
.text:00049784 var_24          = -0x24
.text:00049784 var_20          = -0x20
.text:00049784 var_1C          = -0x1C
.text:00049784 var_18          = -0x18
.text:00049784 var_14          = -0x14
.text:00049784 var_10          = -0x10
.text:00049784
.text:00049784                 PUSH    {R4,R5,LR}
.text:00049788                 SUB     SP, SP, #0x30
.text:0004978C                 MOV     R4, R0
.text:00049790                 LDR     R2, [R4,#8]     ; xLeft
.text:00049794                 MOV     R0, #0x41 ; 'A'
.text:00049798                 STR     R0, [SP,#0x3C+var_10] ; int
.text:0004979C                 MOV     R1, #0xFFFFFF
.text:000497A0                 LDR     R0, =dword_146998
.text:000497A4                 MOV     R5, #1
.text:000497A8                 STR     R1, [SP,#0x3C+var_14] ; int
.text:000497AC                 MOV     R3, #0          ; yTop
.text:000497B0                 LDR     R1, [R0]
.text:000497B4                 LDR     R0, =off_11D9E0 ; "Reading the USB"
.text:000497B8                 STR     R1, [SP,#0x3C+var_18] ; int
.text:000497BC                 MOV     R1, #0x32 ; '2'
.text:000497C0                 STR     R0, [SP,#0x3C+var_1C] ; int
.text:000497C4                 MOV     R0, #0x3C ; '<'
.text:000497C8                 STR     R1, [SP,#0x3C+var_20] ; int
.text:000497CC                 MOV     R1, #0x190
.text:000497D0                 STR     R0, [SP,#0x3C+var_28] ; int
.text:000497D4                 MOV     R0, #0xDA ; 'Ú'
.text:000497D8                 STR     R1, [SP,#0x3C+var_2C] ; wchar_t *
.text:000497DC                 MOV     R1, #0x168
.text:000497E0                 STR     R0, [SP,#0x3C+var_30] ; int
.text:000497E4                 LDR     R0, =dword_146CA4
.text:000497E8                 STR     R1, [SP,#0x3C+var_34] ; int
.text:000497EC                 MOV     R1, #0
.text:000497F0                 STR     R0, [SP,#0x3C+var_38] ; int
.text:000497F4                 STR     R1, [SP,#0x3C+var_3C] ; int
.text:000497F8                 MOV     R1, #0          ; int
.text:000497FC                 LDR     R0, [R4,#0x30]  ; int
.text:00049800                 STR     R5, [SP,#0x3C+var_24] ; int
.text:00049804                 BL      sub_55320
.text:00049808                 LDR     R0, [R4,#0x30]
.text:0004980C                 MOV     R3, #1          ; int
.text:00049810                 STR     R5, [SP,#0x3C+var_3C] ; int
.text:00049814                 LDR     R0, [R0,#0x70]  ; int
.text:00049818                 MOV     R2, #0          ; int
.text:0004981C                 MOV     R1, #0          ; int
.text:00049820                 BL      sub_57990
.text:00049824                 ADD     SP, SP, #0x30 ; '0'
.text:00049828                 POP     {R4,R5,LR}
.text:0004982C                 BX      LR
.text:0004982C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00049830 ; const int off_49830
.text:00049830 off_49830       DCD dword_146CA4        ; DATA XREF: sub_49784+60↑r
.text:00049834 ; const int off_49834
.text:00049834 off_49834       DCD off_11D9E0          ; DATA XREF: sub_49784+30↑r
.text:00049834                                         ; "Reading the USB"
.text:00049838 off_49838       DCD dword_146998        ; DATA XREF: sub_49784+1C↑r
.text:00049838 ; End of function sub_49784
.text:00049838
.text:0004983C
.text:0004983C ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: The issue may be caused due to the encoding of the text. So, if the original encoded text has a size of n bytes, and the code tries to read exactly n bytes, it would be fail when the modified text has a length greater than n bytes.

Comment: So how I can increase the bytes to fulfill the new text considering that I’ve tried to do that and succeeded but with unwanted character in the middle of the text

Comment: It is just one of the possible reasons. Not sure that it is the case, but if it is the case, then you will have to patch the machine code.

Comment: The problem that I can’t understand all the instructions using hex editor I just want to know where I can find the location that could hold the text size

Comment: Your issue has not to do with PE. You can remove PE tag and update the question to take attention for arm programmers.